# Disable mousewheel events on wx.ComboBox widget

Tags: python, combobox, wxpython

I have a wx.Frame with a Combobox. When a selection is made in the Combobox, a specific function is called.

I am having an undesirable effect with the ComboBox.
While the ComboBox has focus, any movement of the mouse wheel changes the selection and, in consequence, a different function is triggered.

In practice it is very difficult to remember you have to put the widget out of focus to 'save' your original selection, so that, as the functions triggered take each several seconds to complete, usability of the GUI is not good.

I tried to catch the mouse event to no avail using

> self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, self.donothing, self.mycombobox)

Which would be the best procedure to prevent mouse signals to affect the combobox ?

*EDIT

If you want to play with code, here is some you can execute and test.
Just execute, make a selection with mouse and then play de mousewheel. I do not want the selection to change. I have not been able to catch the event, whatever it is, emitted by the mousewheel.*

```
import wx

class Myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        pan = wx.Panel(self)

        self.cbx = wx.ComboBox(pan, -1, pos=(10,30),
                            choices=["SEARCH", "SELECT", "PASS"],
                            style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN )

        self.cbx_2 = wx.ComboBox(pan, -1, pos=(10,60),
                            choices=["LOOK", "GO", "FILL"],
                            style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN )

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, self.do_nothing)  # to no avail
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.on_selection, self.cbx)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.on_selection_2, self.cbx_2)

    def on_selection(self, evt):
        """I do not want this to be executed inadvertently when 
         moving mousewheel"""
        print self.cbx.GetStringSelection()
        #evt.Skip(False)  # this is the default behavior anyway

    def on_selection_2(self, evt):
        """this is another combobox. dont mind if mouse move it or not"""
        print self.cbx.GetStringSelection()

    def do_nothing(self, evt):
        ""
        print 'on events pit' # never catched !!!        
        #evt.Skip(False)  # this is the default behavior anyway


if __name__ == "__main__":  
    App = wx.PySimpleApp()
    Myframe().Show()
    App.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I would use ComboCtrl widgets under wx.combo module since they do not change the selections according to mouse wheel.

Comment: Don't use `sizer = wx.BoxSizer(self.mycombobox.CaptureMouse)`. so ignore capturing mouse ! @joaquin

Comment: And,  elsewhere defined mouse capture, you must cancel the event if you have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another pair of eyes required.

```
import wx

class Myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        pan = wx.Panel(self)
        self.cbx = wx.ComboBox(pan, -1, pos=(10,30),
                                choices=["SEARCH", "SELECT",
                                         "PASS", "LOG", "DATABASE"],
                                style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN )
        self.cbx_2 = wx.ComboBox(pan, -1, pos=(10,60),
                            choices=["LOOK", "GO", "FILL"],
                            style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN )

        self.cbx.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, self.do_nothing)
        self.cbx.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.on_selection)
        self.cbx_2.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, self.do_nothing)
        self.cbx_2.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.on_selection_2)

    def on_selection(self, evt):
        """I do not want this to be executed inadvertently when 
         moving mousewheel"""
        print self.cbx.GetStringSelection()

    def on_selection_2(self, evt):
        """this is another combobox. dont mind if mouse move it or not"""
        print self.cbx.GetStringSelection()

    def do_nothing(self, evt):
        print 'on events pit'

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    App = wx.PySimpleApp()
    Myframe().Show()
    App.MainLoop()
```

`self.Bind` and `self.widget.Bind` differences are [explained in the wxPyWiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind)

Comment: Thanks, It works, but just for the minimal example I gave. I you have another combobox or another widget, the wheel effect is still there. I updated the code to show it. Sorry I was not expecting, reducing the number of widgets to only one the event could be catched !!!.

Comment: Compare my bind commands with yours, that is the key. Change the code to bind on to self.cbx_2 as well and it will still function properly. On second thoughts, I'll repost give me a minute or two.

Comment: Thanks !. I should have known the answer... but I got stuck with the code !!. I added a link to your answer. Already explained in other SO posts, but think can be useful to others looking for hints